# How To Make Nested Tables With Responsive Design Compatible With Gmail

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, gmail

I'm currently working on an email campaign that appears and functions on all devices that I've tested so far EXCEPT for Gmail. I want the table cells to collapse into blocks once the screen size reduces, yet, while Gmail recognizes all CSS declarations prior to the media query, it recognizes no declarations within the media query and allows the email no responsive design. This is the most important declaration that I am trying to make work.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){table, thead, tbody, th, td { 
    width: 100% !important;
    display:block !important;
}
```

Here is a link to the email which appears and functions exactly how I want it to: https://www.spectrumemp.com/archives/email/d3ded4a4-3095-11e9-820b-22000ab3b6d0. Any suggestions as to what the problem or solution might be would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail and several other email clients strip  tags out of the html.  This is why it's best to inline as much of you CSS as possible.  This is especially true when it comes to rows and columns.

The best way to ensure cross-client compatibility is to use an inlining tool like [Zurb](https://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html).  The beauty of this is that it will give you 100% responsive email templates and be cross-client compatible. It will also allow you to do most of the actually coding in SASS which will speed up production.

Comment: I read that website thoroughly and learned a lot of useful information while also inlining all of my CSS. However, it did not help me with my specific issue. While most of the countless sources that I've searched have recommended using the code I listed above to stack the tables, I haven't seen one say how the method changes with Gmail. I've tried even switching the table cells to tables within table cells, yet that changed nothing.